# Hide iOS Keyboard Predictive Text Bar - UITextView / UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

Seems that setting

`autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;`

for a **UITextView** or **UITextField** no longer sufficient to hide the iOS keyboard's predictive bar.

Has Apple decided that this can only be hidden by the user in keyboard settings? Or this there still some way to do this programmatically? We need to do this for our app that includes spelling exercises.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This removes the predictive text bar for me:

```
@IBOutlet var tf: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no
    tf.spellCheckingType = .no
}
```

Comment: So you need to subclass to achieve this?

Comment: no just create outlet off UITextField

Comment: @Peter - no, no need to subclass. That code is just an example of setting both properties to `.no` via code. If you've added your text field in Storyboard and want to do it there, set both **Correction** and **Spell Checking** to `No` in the Attributes Inspector pane.

Comment: Forgot to also set spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo. Working now. Thanks.